# Bayes theorem with errors

Tags: bayesian, uncertainty

I have a situation in which I want to calculate, for a given $y$ (which I measure experimentally), the probability distribution of $x$ i.e. $p(x|y)$ (actually what I need is the value of x for which this is maximized). Using Bayes theorem I have $p(x|y) = \frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{p(y)}$. I know both $p(x)$ and $p(y|x)$ which are both Gaussians. I don't know $p(y)$, but given that $y$ is constant for a given measurement, and all that I need is the maximum value over x, that shouldn't matter. However, in practice, I have an error associated to $y$, call it $dy$ ($y$ is Gaussian distributed). How can I account for this uncertainty on $y$ when trying to find the best $x$ (and the uncertainty on $x$)? Thank you!

Comment: If you swapped $y$ with $x$ just for notation's sake, it would probably be less confusing. We typically talk about $Y|X$, not the other way around.

Comment: But that would just changed the notation, right? It wouldn't fix the issue

Comment: If you know that $y$ is distributed normally, just plug it in as $p(y)$ in the formula. While the value of $y$ influencing $x$ may be a constant, $y$ is still a random variable because you aren't certain about its value. The uncertainty of your belief is reflected in the existence of the measurement error.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. For example in practice I measure (say) y=3 and I know that (say) dy=0.1. Assuming p(y) is normally distributed I can get p(y), but that will still be a constant for that given measurement i.e. p(y) is the same for all x, no?

Comment: Yes, my comment only concerns notation. It does not solve the actual problem.

Comment: If you observe $y^\star=y+\epsilon$, you need to replace $p(y)$ with the distribution of $y^\star$, $p^\star(y^\star)$, which is a convolution of $p(\cdot)$ by the distribution of $\epsilon$. Same thing for $p(y|x)$, to be replaced by $p^\star(y^\star|x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically, the Bayes formula is the same, just with the replacement of p(y) and p(y|x) by p*(y*) and p*(y*|x)?